# What type of a light switch is this?

Tags: lighting, switch

I have a light switch controlling outdoor lights. Turning on and off the lights take a second with this switch. It has a light indicator on it. When it’s on, the top right light is on. When it’s off, the bottom light is on. There is something at the bottom of the switch, not sure what it is.

Here is the picture:
[image]

Comment: Take off the faceplate by removing the 2 screws. Take pictures of the inside of the box. Hopefully that will provide enough information to identify it. If not, turn off the circuit breaker and remove the switch (but do *not* disconnect any wires) and get a picture of the label on the back.

Comment: DO you  have a problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I removed the face plate and figured out that this is a C4-APDKD adaptive phase dimmer. I was curious about switch, because I installed motion sensor lights outside and they act weird (turn on/off a few times and then stay on). I thought the switch was causing the problem.

Comment: dimmers and lights with electronics (motion sensors, smart bulbs) in them don't really like each other.

Comment: I might suggest that you ask about your _real_ question. The type of switch here may or may not be the cause.